# Facebook - Multiple Pages connected to Single App and routing to different Webhooks

Tags: facebook, chatbot, facebook-apps, facebook-messenger

I have multiple chatbots, each with their own webhook endpoint. (Really its multiple instances of the same chatbot)

I have multiple Facebook Pages that match each chatbot (instance).

I would like to have a single FB App, that goes through the Review Process and Business Verification, and then route my Facebook Pages messages, through that app and route them to the single appropriate webhook for that page.

**Is this possible?**

---

If not, then what if I built a single webhook that did the routing based on the Page ID?

**The goal** is to not have to create multiple apps, and go through the entire process for each one, every time a new client requires a new instance of the same chatbot.

Comment: No, you can not have multiple webhook URLs based on pages. _“If not, then what if I built a single webhook that did the routing based on the Page ID?”_ - then what? That is standard practice of course.

Comment: Felt like a work-around so wanted to check for built-in functionality first, but if that's the standard practice, then great. If you describe a "routing webhook" in an answer, then I'll accept it as correct.